# Changing NSMenuItem depending on user selection

Tags: cocoa, menuitem, document-based

I am working on a Cocoa document based application. I have a menu item in the file menu named *"Export Things…"*. This menu item is connected to the first responder, and calls a selector in *MyDocument*. So far so good.

I would like to change the title of this menu item depending on user selection. If the user has nothing selected, it should read *"Export All Things…"*, when the user has some things selected it should read *"Export Selected Things…"*. When no document is open, it should just read *"Export Things…"*.

Where and when should I change this menu item? I figure I can just change the menu item using *setTitle:*, but how do I get a reference to the NSMenuItem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement `-validateMenuItem:` in the responder class that handles the menu item's action. It should return a BOOL (which indicates whether the item is enabled), but you also get a reference to the `NSMenuItem` as a parameter that you can use to change the title.

To decide which menu item you're dealing with, you should inspect its `action`, e.g.

```
- (BOOL)validateMenuItem:(NSMenuItem *)item {
  if ([item action] == @selector(export:)) {
    if (hasSelection) {
      [item setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Export Selected Things",nil)];
    } else {
      [item setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Export All Things",nil)];
    }
  }
  return YES;
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks a lot! The only minor issue is that the menu item is not reset to a default title when the document is closed. But I guess that is accceptable, since it is greyed out anyway.